# Why do I get an undefined when logging a custom function with an object using object initializers within it?

Tags: javascript

I am learning more about objects in JavaScript and I learned to create an object like this:

```
const myObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    answerToUniverse: 42,
    'olly olly': 'oxen free',
    sayHello: function() {
      return 'hello';
    },
  };
```

So I thought I could create the same type of object within a custom function like this:

```
function createMyObject() {
  const myObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    answerToUniverse: 42,
    'olly olly': 'oxen free',
    sayHello: function() {
      return 'hello';
    },
  };
}

console.log(createMyObject());
```

but when I log it, I get `undefined`.

I know that a better way to write it is like this:

```
function createMyObject() {
  return {
    foo: 'bar',
    answerToUniverse: 42,
    'olly olly': 'oxen free',
    sayHello: function() {
      return 'hello';
    },
  };
}
```

But isn't there a way to successfully create an object within a custom function with an object initializer in the code? It seems like it should work.

Comment: It looks like you already answered your own question.  If you want to log the return value of `createMyObject()` to the console, it needs to return something.  Which you do in your last example.  Both examples successfully create an object.  One of them returns that object from the function, the other one doesn't.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your first function *creates an object*, but that object only exists within that function because you don't return it to outside the function...

Comment: `return myObject;` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function does not end with a `return` statement, it's the same thing as ending with `return undefined;` So your code is equivalent to:

```
function createMyObject() {
  const myObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    answerToUniverse: 42,
    'olly olly': 'oxen free',
    sayHello: function() {
      return 'hello';
    },
  };
  // myObject is never used.
  // it is also not visible outside this function,
  // so declaring it here has no effect unless it
  // is returned from the function.
  return undefined;
}

console.log(createMyObject()); // simplifies to console.log(undefined);
```

Comment: Sure thing Eric, SO was making me wait 4 minutes before I could mark it and upvote it. Thanks again!